# What is the working logic of Row Arrangement in Android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, horizontal-alignment

I've been currently developing and learning android jetpack compose and there are some things I don't know and wonder about this. One thing I'm wondering I'm trying to do a back button positioned in the upper left corner of the screen and a text positioned in the middle. I originally wrote this code like this:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(5.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onBackClick()
                }
                .padding(4.dp),
            alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back),
            contentDescription = "back")
        
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center){
            Text(text = "Help")
        }
    }
```

Since I gave a **modifier.FillMaxWidth** in the first **Row**, I didn't give it in the second because it has a child component, I thought it was unnecessary, and I gave a **horizontalArrangment** center in the second **Row** to align the **Text** in the middle, but even though I did this, the back button and the text appeared side by side on the upper left.

However, when I rewrote my code like this, when I added the second Row modifier.FillMaxWidth, it worked fine.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
        .padding(5.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onBackClick()
                }
                .padding(4.dp),
            alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_back),
            contentDescription = "back")
        
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), // <----
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center){
            Text(text = "Yardım")
        }
    }
```

I added this **modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()** second Row component

Why is it necessary to give **Modifier.fillMaxWidth()** on the second **Row**? We already give it in the parent component? what's going on in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`horizontalArrangement`** in the `Row` =  the horizontal arrangement of the layout's children in the **available space**.

Using:

```
   Row(modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .background(Yellow),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
   ) {
        Text(text = "Yardım")
   }
```

[image]

Using:

```
   Row(modifier = Modifier
          //.fillMaxWidth()
          .background(Yellow),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
   ) {
        Text(text = "Yardım")
   }
```

[image]

In any case using this layout the `Text(text = "Yardım")` is not centered in the whole 1st `Row` but only in the space occupied by the 2nd `Row`.

If you want to center the text in the whole 1st `Row` you can use a `Box` as parent container.
In this case use the **`align`** modifier in the children to a specific `Alignment` within the `Box`. This alignment will have priority over the `Box`'s `alignment` parameter.

Something like:

```
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .background(Yellow), 
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ){
            Text(text = "Yardım")
        }

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
            //.....
        )
        
    }
```

[image]